# Is it possible to join a bot conversation from a console application?

Tags: bots, botframework

Is it possible to join a bot conversation from a console application ( using the Microsoft bot Framework ) ? My customer is trying to test a bot, but so far has to have a person join a conversation in order to do that.

Comment: hi, what bot conversation? are you meaning like a AI or a online bot?

Comment: I thought I was posting in the microsoft bot framework board, sorry.  So the bot is composed using the microsoft bot framework, and they have an emulator you can use to test.  I'm wonding if there is a console app one can build to join the conversation so that you could, for example, fire up 300 conversations and measure the back-ends.

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework team does not provide an application of this nature. However, you are free to build an application to do this so long as you remain within Azure terms of service. The [Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Microsoft Bot Framework allows you to interact with bots through the *Direct Line API*, eliminating the need for a user interface. Using this API, you can send and receive messages from a bot.

These code snippets below showcase how you can initiate a conversation, send a message from the user to the bot, and subsequently receive the bot's response.

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string directLineSecret = "YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET";
        string botId = "YOUR_BOT_ID";

        var directLineClient = new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret);

        var conversation = await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Bot: Hello! Type 'exit' to end the conversation.");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("You: ");
            string userMessage = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userMessage.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                break;
            }

            await SendMessageToBot(directLineClient, conversation.ConversationId, userMessage);

            var botResponse = await ReceiveMessageFromBot(directLineClient, conversation.ConversationId);
            Console.WriteLine($"Bot: {botResponse?.Text}");
        }
    }

    static async Task SendMessageToBot(DirectLineClient client, string conversationId, string messageText)
    {
        var userMessage = new Activity
        {
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
            Text = messageText,
            From = new ChannelAccount("User"),
        };

        await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversationId, userMessage);
    }

    static async Task<Activity> ReceiveMessageFromBot(DirectLineClient client, string conversationId)
    {
        var response = await client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(conversationId);
        var activities = response.Activities;

        var botResponse = activities.FirstOrDefault(a => a.From.Id == botId && a.Type == ActivityTypes.Message);

        return botResponse;
    }
}
```

You need to follow these steps to be able to handle this issue:

**Direct Line Secret and Bot ID:** You should substitute the directLineSecret and botId variables with your bot's Direct Line Secret and Bot ID.

**Required Libraries:** To make the code functional, you need to add Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine library to your project. You can add this library through NuGet Package Manager or .NET CLI.

**Direct Line API:** The code communicates with a bot using the Direct Line API. Therefore, ensure that your Direct Line API is operational and accessible.

After following the above steps and making the necessary changes, you can interact with your bot through a C# console app using this code example.